# pg_dump does not full copy of db

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, database-indexes, pg-dump, reindex

I have a database db1 which works very slow. It executes hard queries with joins few minutes. I created a copy of that database: db2. Then I created and tuned some indexes and that db2 began to work much faster! After that my goal was to tune db1 working fast as db2. I made copy of db2 (pg_dump -Fc db2 > db2.dump) and restore it to new db1. Then I tested it's speed. But the speed of work not the same! The new db1 much slower (as it was before). What's the problem here? Does pg_dump dumps everything inside db? Data, indexes and so on? Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

After loading,the statictics tables are still empty (they are not part of the dump). You need to run [analyze](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-analyze.html) manually.[as explained in the postgres manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/backup-dump.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes `pg_dump` dump all object definitions, table, view, indexes, type and do on. You have reset the cache and destroy all staistics, so when running the same query in a fresh restore you may encounter bad query times, you can do an `ANALYZE` to refresh all the stats, but consider that you have now in your cluster **db2 + db1** instead of **only db1** as before, so the cache is less available for db1, you have to destroy db2 before doing your analyze.